# findstr ms-dos command won't search sub directories

Tags: windows, findstr

I had to switch off my windows search indexing in Windows 7 as the old hard disk was constantly making noise with indexing switched on!

Now I want to use **Windows command prompt to search for a specific text term within all files located within the current directory and sub directories**

How do I use the Windiows command **findstr** to search subdirectories?

Currently, when I open a command prompt and change directory to `C:\Users\Damien\Documents\Research\2012July` and run the command `findstr "thesis" *.tex /S`, I get the following error :

```
FINDSTR: Cannot open /s
```

This command will search  the current directory if I remove /S, but I want to be able to search for text within subfolders also.

Comment: Posting as comment, since I know this isn't the answer you want, but: install Cygwin (www.cygwin.org) and you'll have a full set of consistent, functional, well-documented command-line tools that always just work. The UNIX `find` command is infinitely more flexible and powerful -- and of course can do what you want here.

Answer (score 31):

You need to put `/S` at the beginning, i.e.:

```
findstr /S "thesis" *.tex
```

From the built in help:

```
C:\>findstr /?
Searches for strings in files.

FINDSTR [/B] [/E] [/L] [/R] [/S] [/I] [/X] [/V] [/N] [/M] [/O] [/P] [/F:file]
        [/C:string] [/G:file] [/D:dir list] [/A:color attributes] [/OFF[LINE]]
        strings [[drive:][path]filename[ ...]]
```

Your modifiers/switches, whatever they are called, need to come **before** your pattern/string

Comment: @Jon How would I structure the syntax if I also want to indicate the path (i.e. findstr /S "some_string" *.txt PATH?) where and how would I indicate the path for the folder with the sub-folders I want to search. Thank you

Answer (score 8):

You have your arguments in the wrong order, try this:

```
findstr /S "thesis" *.tex
```