# find (ms-dos command) looking into sub directories files

Tags: windows-7, cmd

I am trying to use find to look for files that contain a specific keyword. To my understanding, find takes in a file not a directory (that's why it is giving me error). So is there a way i can go through each sub-directories and look into each and every file to execute the find command so that I can get the result of all files that contains the given keyword? (Much like grep)

So far i got this:
find \S "keyword" "directory\ *"

Error i am getting:

Access denied - Directory name

Access denied - Directory name

.
.
.

Anyone give me a hint? I am current using window 7 right now.

Comment: For examples on how to do this with findstr, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9097034/findstr-ms-dos-command-wont-search-sub-directories.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`FIND` does not take the `/s` switch (not `\s` - that's a directory)

`FINDSTR` is another animal.

About the only quibble about the documentation avaliable from `findstr /?` from the prompt is that you can target a filemask in a specified directory by specifying `\dirname\*`, not simply in the current directory as documented. There is also an option to run against a semicolon-delimiter list of directory names - but I've never seen it used.

Comment: Note that the *RTFM* comment was removed by a moderator because your post was flagged. Don't add it back please.